# Hello! I have a flutter app and I have another that’s a template. How can I take a page from the template app and add it to my existing one?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a flutter app and a template. How can I take a page from the template app and add it to my existing one?

For example, the template app has a news tab. I like it’s layout and would like to add it to my existing app. How can I do this?

This is how my app structure looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Flutter is built on the concept of components where everything (even the app itself, is a widget).

To do this, just look at the widget that describes the page you are trying to merge with yours, then modify it.

Also this is not really a proper question. If you need help with any source code, or if you come across bugs, then please use StackOverflow for that. You can paste logs, your source code, etc, into this post, and we (the community) can all help you.